# ubuntu /dev folder restore

Tags: ubuntu, restore

I am new to Linux.  I created a folder `/dev/test/` in Ubuntu. When I rebooted the server, the folder was no longer there.  What happened to the folder?  What would have caused it to disappear?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a folder called dev on root, there is already a system folder on root called dev for "devices" not development. Also you will not be able to create a folder on root without root or sudo. Create your folder under your home directory.